# From octave to python

Tags: python, matlab, octave

I translated this lines of octave into  python  ,  but  the results  are  not the  same, can  someone tell  where is  the  problem? i can  provide  the  csv  if  needeed

**Octave:**

```
Fs = 500;     % Frequence d'echantillonnage
Fn = Fs/2;    % Frequence de Nyquist
figure(1)
T = csvread('./ADCSamplesOctave.csv');
subplot(2,3,1);plot(T(:,2));title('Raw ECG signal');xlabel('Samples (Fs=500Hz)');ylabel('Magnitude (output of an 11-bit ADC)');


fBaseLine=fir1(128, 5/Fn, 'high');
fBaseLine
```

**Python :**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import firwin, lfilter
import csv

Fs = 500  
Fn = Fs / 2  
fig = plt.figure(1)

ecg_signal = []
with open('./ADCSamplesOctave.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        ecg_signal.append(float(row[1]))

plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)
plt.plot(ecg_signal)
plt.title('Raw ECG signal')
plt.xlabel('Samples (Fs=500Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (output of an 11-bit ADC)')

fBaseLine = firwin(129, 5 / Fn, pass_zero=False)  # "high" filter
print(fBaseLine)
```

*python  results : *

```
[ 3.06481816e-04  2.96599543e-04  2.88853370e-04  2.82568524e-04
  2.76939286e-04  2.71033690e-04  2.63799868e-04  2.54074015e-04
  2.40589905e-04  2.21989891e-04  1.96837306e-04  1.63630147e-04
  1.20815920e-04  6.68075226e-05  1.00902679e-18 -8.12119837e-05
 -1.78416126e-04 -2.93164101e-04 -4.26953003e-04 -5.81206792e-04
 -7.57257960e-04 -9.56329590e-04 -1.17951801e-03 -1.42777626e-03
 -1.70189848e-03 -2.00250547e-03 -2.33003162e-03 -2.68471321e-03
 -3.06657840e-03 -3.47543896e-03 -3.91088381e-03 -4.37227461e-03
 -4.85874325e-03 -5.36919155e-03 -5.90229304e-03 -6.45649686e-03
 -7.03003384e-03 -7.62092465e-03 -8.22699010e-03 -8.84586330e-03
 -9.47500390e-03 -1.01117139e-02 -1.07531556e-02 -1.13963702e-02
 -1.20382988e-02 -1.26758042e-02 -1.33056929e-02 -1.39247397e-02
 -1.45297107e-02 -1.51173888e-02 -1.56845976e-02 -1.62282267e-02
 -1.67452552e-02 -1.72327763e-02 -1.76880199e-02 -1.81083747e-02
 -1.84914095e-02 -1.88348924e-02 -1.91368091e-02 -1.93953795e-02
 -1.96090716e-02 -1.97766146e-02 -1.98970092e-02 -1.99695355e-02
  9.79694208e-01 -1.99695355e-02 -1.98970092e-02 -1.97766146e-02
 -1.96090716e-02 -1.93953795e-02 -1.91368091e-02 -1.88348924e-02
 -1.84914095e-02 -1.81083747e-02 -1.76880199e-02 -1.72327763e-02
 -1.67452552e-02 -1.62282267e-02 -1.56845976e-02 -1.51173888e-02
 -1.45297107e-02 -1.39247397e-02 -1.33056929e-02 -1.26758042e-02
 -1.20382988e-02 -1.13963702e-02 -1.07531556e-02 -1.01117139e-02
 -9.47500390e-03 -8.84586330e-03 -8.22699010e-03 -7.62092465e-03
 -7.03003384e-03 -6.45649686e-03 -5.90229304e-03 -5.36919155e-03
 -4.85874325e-03 -4.37227461e-03 -3.91088381e-03 -3.47543896e-03
 -3.06657840e-03 -2.68471321e-03 -2.33003162e-03 -2.00250547e-03
 -1.70189848e-03 -1.42777626e-03 -1.17951801e-03 -9.56329590e-04
 -7.57257960e-04 -5.81206792e-04 -4.26953003e-04 -2.93164101e-04
 -1.78416126e-04 -8.12119837e-05  1.00902679e-18  6.68075226e-05
  1.20815920e-04  1.63630147e-04  1.96837306e-04  2.21989891e-04
  2.40589905e-04  2.54074015e-04  2.63799868e-04  2.71033690e-04
  2.76939286e-04  2.82568524e-04  2.88853370e-04  2.96599543e-04
  3.06481816e-04]
```

*octave results :*

```
Columns 1 through 8:

   2.4893e-04   2.3553e-04   2.2358e-04   2.1229e-04   2.0081e-04   1.8815e-04   1.7324e-04   1.5493e-04

 Columns 9 through 16:

   1.3198e-04   1.0309e-04   6.6897e-05   2.2017e-05  -3.2976e-05  -9.9516e-05  -1.7904e-04  -2.7295e-04

 Columns 17 through 24:

  -3.8264e-04  -5.0944e-04  -6.5462e-04  -8.1936e-04  -1.0048e-03  -1.2118e-03  -1.4413e-03  -1.6940e-03

 Columns 25 through 32:

  -1.9706e-03  -2.2713e-03  -2.5964e-03  -2.9460e-03  -3.3200e-03  -3.7181e-03  -4.1396e-03  -4.5840e-03

 Columns 33 through 40:

  -5.0503e-03  -5.5374e-03  -6.0439e-03  -6.5684e-03  -7.1092e-03  -7.6645e-03  -8.2321e-03  -8.8100e-03

 Columns 41 through 48:

  -9.3958e-03  -9.9871e-03  -1.0581e-02  -1.1176e-02  -1.1768e-02  -1.2354e-02  -1.2933e-02  -1.3500e-02

 Columns 49 through 56:

  -1.4054e-02  -1.4591e-02  -1.5108e-02  -1.5604e-02  -1.6074e-02  -1.6517e-02  -1.6931e-02  -1.7312e-02

 Columns 57 through 64:

  -1.7659e-02  -1.7970e-02  -1.8244e-02  -1.8478e-02  -1.8671e-02  -1.8822e-02  -1.8931e-02  -1.8997e-02

 Columns 65 through 72:

   9.8073e-01  -1.8997e-02  -1.8931e-02  -1.8822e-02  -1.8671e-02  -1.8478e-02  -1.8244e-02  -1.7970e-02

 Columns 73 through 80:
-1.7659e-02  -1.7312e-02  -1.6931e-02  -1.6517e-02  -1.6074e-02  -1.5604e-02  -1.5108e-02  -1.4591e-02

 Columns 81 through 88:

  -1.4054e-02  -1.3500e-02  -1.2933e-02  -1.2354e-02  -1.1768e-02  -1.1176e-02  -1.0581e-02  -9.9871e-03

 Columns 89 through 96:

  -9.3958e-03  -8.8100e-03  -8.2321e-03  -7.6645e-03  -7.1092e-03  -6.5684e-03  -6.0439e-03  -5.5374e-03

 Columns 97 through 104:

  -5.0503e-03  -4.5840e-03  -4.1396e-03  -3.7181e-03  -3.3200e-03  -2.9460e-03  -2.5964e-03  -2.2713e-03

 Columns 105 through 112:

  -1.9706e-03  -1.6940e-03  -1.4413e-03  -1.2118e-03  -1.0048e-03  -8.1936e-04  -6.5462e-04  -5.0944e-04

 Columns 113 through 120:

  -3.8264e-04  -2.7295e-04  -1.7904e-04  -9.9516e-05  -3.2976e-05   2.2017e-05   6.6897e-05   1.0309e-04

 Columns 121 through 128:

   1.3198e-04   1.5493e-04   1.7324e-04   1.8815e-04   2.0081e-04   2.1229e-04   2.2358e-04   2.3553e-04

 Column 129:

   2.4893e-04
```

Comment: Can you please edit the post with the results from both octave and python?

Comment: Hi, looks like there's an open bug on Octave relating to this issue: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?56170. There's also some info there on how to better replicate matlab/ python results in octave in this area (basically use  the least squares method "firls" instead of fir1)

Answer (score 4):

The results are not the same, but they are very close. The discrepancy comes from round-off errors and differences in the implementation of the Octave fir1 function versus the Python firwin function. Understanding where the differences come from would involve understanding the implementation of both functions in detail.

Here are your results from python (X) vs octave (Y)
[image: Seemingly perfect alignment]

Zooming in on the origin:
[image]